# Uploading image from input field and still getting validation error saying that field is required

Tags: php, laravel, forms, controller

Route Code:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth', 'prefix' => 'admin'], function(){
    Route::resource('gallery', GalleryController::class);
});
```

The Form I'm Using to Upload the File:

```
<form action="{{ route('gallery.store') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf

<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <div class="custom-file">
        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="gallery_img" id="inputGroupFile01">
        <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01">Choose file</label>
        
    </div>
</div>
@error('gal_img')
    <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
@enderror

<div class="input-group-append">
    <div class="col-sm-10" style="padding-left: 1px;">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Save</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller Code:

```
    public function store(GalleryRequests $request)
{
    $gal_img = $request->file('gallery_img');
    $gal_file = date('YmdHi').$gal_img->getClientOriginalName();
    $gal_img->move(public_path('upload/gallery'), $gal_file);
    $save_path = 'upload/gallery/'.$gal_file;

    Gallery::insert([
        'gal_img' => $save_path
    ]);

    $notification = array(
        'message' => 'Slider Inserted Successfully',
        'alert-type' => 'success'
    );

    return redirect()->back()->with($notification);
}
```

Request file validation:

```
 public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'gal_img' => 'required'
    ];
}

public function messages(){
    return [
        'gal_img.required' => 'Please Select an Image First',
    ];
}
```

The error I get when trying to save after selecting an Image:
[image]

Trying to figure out what I've done wrong for hours and am so frustrated right now, please help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: something not right in the code you posted.  Your file input is named gallery_image but you say that the error message is shown.  However, your error message is looking at `gal_img`  which makes me think that this is not your code, but rather a cut down version, which makes it difficult to detect the problem.

Comment: This is entirely my code, I just used a different name in the input field....however let me check if this is the issue. Will let u know @Snapey

Comment: @Snapey Exactly that is detection of problem. Already wrote an answer.

Comment: @Snapey You were right! The naming should have been the same in both the input and request files, this is such a shame! Thanks a lot for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Field in form is named `gallery_img` so that name has to be checked:

```
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'gallery_img' => 'required'
    ];
}

public function messages()
{
    return [
        'gallery_img.required' => 'Please Select an Image First',
    ];
}
```